# laravel updateOrCreate() with dynamic table

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm working with project where tables are created all the time depending on user adding new properties, so for my model i have below

```
    class Hotel extends Model
{
    public function __construct($hotel)
    {
        $this->table = $hotel;
    }

    protected $fillable = ['date', 'sold', 'sold_diff', 'rev', 'rev_diff', 'row', 'date_col', 'sold_col', 'rev_col'];

}
```

and i can use the table in controller by doing

```
$hotel_table = new Hotel($table);
```

but i like to use Model::updateOrCreate() when I'm adding or updating rows in table, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the signature for the updateOrCreate function 
"static Model updateOrCreate( array $attributes, array $values = array())"

For you to update or create, you can pass the condition that must be met to update the table to the first argument and the values to be updated to the second.

for example.

```
  $primaryKey = isset($request->input('id')) ? $request->input('id') : null;

  $myModel = Model::updateOrCreate(['id' => $primaryKey], $request->all());
```

so with this if **id** is in the request object the table will be updated but if not a new record will be created.

Comment: i may not have asked question correctly, but basically what i want to know is how can i chain methods like updateOrCreate() or all() or get() since I'm calling $hotel_table = new Hotel($table);  i have to do it this way since Hotel model requires constructor.

Comment: you can do $hotel_table = (new Hotel($table))->all(); or               $hotel_table = (new Hotel($table))->updateOrCreate(['id' => $primaryKey], $request->all()); if i get you right.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 you can use simply like this

```
    class Hotel extends Model
    {
        protect $table = 'hotels'

        protected $fillable = ['date', 'sold', 'sold_diff', 'rev', 'rev_diff', 'row', 'date_col', 'sold_col', 'rev_col'];
// protected $guarded = []; you can use this instead of `$fillable` this is for all columns fillable

    }
```

now in your controller you can use

```
Model::update();
Model::create();
```

Comment: wait so how is table being set? the whole reason I have constructor is because there are many tables for different hotels and they are being added all the time so when I need add data specific hotel I need to set that table to Hotel model.

Comment: if you have same attribute for each hotels create two tables and use foreign key im not clear about your requirement